# Oracle ADF: Tree Navigation Oracle Alta UI Design Pattern

Tags: jsf-2.2, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have created page with tree navigation with the help of the following blog.

[Implementing the Tree Navigation Oracle Alta UI Design Pattern](https://blogs.oracle.com/shay/entry/implementing_the_tree_navigation_oracle)

The blog is really very good. I have created the following two pages using the above blog.

[image]

[image]

Actually the above tree navigation is created using Hr Schema. I need to create the same Tree navigation fro some menu system. But I don't have any Db Tables for that. I need to hard code in application. And the final menu item (for example in the above image **Susan** should be a clickable item. When user click this I need to show some data in the center panel.My menu should look like as follows

[image]

In the above image final menu items are Accounts Payble, Accounts Receivable, Purchase , Sales and Inventory. I need to create Tree navigation for this menu model. And when user click any item like sales or Inventory I have to show some data in center panel. How do I acieve this. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the items in the menu be af:link and then code something in their actionListener - for example you can have the code set the content of the right side using dynamic Regions, or possibly just an af:deck component that shows different content on the right side.